# Selenium throwing [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer with any python pause

Tags: python, selenium

I'm stepping through my selenium code to sort out code improvements; or using raw_input() to pause so that I can interact with the browser to click manually as a validation.

This happens even if I type in the code at the REPL and don't immediately follow a driver commend, such as :

```html
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/rizwank/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 323, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/rizwank/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 309, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Users/rizwank/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 460, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Users/rizwank/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 484, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

What am I doing wrong here?

ipdb> driver.capabilities
{'acceptInsecureCerts': True, 'browserName': 'firefox', 'browserVersion': '61.0', 'moz:accessibilityChecks': False, 'moz:headless': False, 'moz:processID': 32018, 'moz:profile': '/var/folders/hz/dn93qm_j4jgdgrmzflb39sm00000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.SCm3GIMU9Ac4', 'moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin': False, 'moz:webdriverClick': True, 'pageLoadStrategy': 'normal', 'platformName': 'darwin', 'platformVersion': '17.6.0', 'rotatable': False, 'timeouts': {'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000}}

Selenium 3.8.0
geckodriver-v0.21.0-macos.tar.gz

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Doesn't happen in Chrome.

Comment: _Selenium Client_ / _WebDriver_ / _WebClient_ variant and versions please.

Comment: My specific issue got solved. I used a Firefox Profile in the webdriver and I need to load this profile every time again before I fire up the webdriver (didn't realize that before)

Comment: @CorneeldH can you explain more?

Comment: @DebanjanB added!

Comment: I think my problem is different, my code is like this:
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/location/firefox/profile/blabla.test')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, executable_path = geckodriver_path)
... do stufff....
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, executable_path = geckodriver_path)
That went wrong. Now, before the second driver I declare fp again. That works. Good luck with your issue!

Comment: I am getting this issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5296. I was able to work around it by adding a time.sleep(1) after driver.quit().